# What costs are involved in an open sourced project compared to a non open sourced project?

Tags: software, finance, business

Often if employing a team to program a project you would need to pay: the programmers, office space, etc.

**My question:**

In open source projects is it common for the programmers to be volunteers? Are there any other costs that you don't have compared to closed-source projects and vice-versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends on the project.

There are pure volunteer projects with a budget of zero. I have taken part in such projects myself and surprisingly it works when the problem is interesting enough. But you can not really rely on anything getting finished on time or getting finished at all, because all contributors work in their free-time and can stop working at any time when more important priorities appear in their life, they find a more interesting hobby or they get into personal conflicts with other project members.

But there are also open source projects which are carried almost entirely by paid developers employed by one or more companies. Some of these projects don't accept any outside contributions at all and only release the finished product to the public. With such projects, the budget does not differ at all from a proprietary project.

And then there are projects anywhere in between where a certain percentage of work is done by volunteers and a certan percentage by employees. The [2015 Linux Kernel report](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/news-media/blogs/browse/2015/02/linux-kernel-report-more-contributors-ever), for example, reads: *"more developers than ever are paid for their work; a conservative calculation shows this number at 80 percent. Volunteer developers don’t stay that way for long, as companies continue to aggressively recruit the best Linux talent."*. Note that in such projects, volunteer work isn't completely free, because it needs to be coordinated and reviewed by maintainers who are usually employed.